# How to disable HTML scrolling

Tags: html, css

Here is my codes

```html
<iframe width="695" height="391" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/60ItHLz5WEA" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I tried `style="overflow: hidden"` and `scrolling="no"` but both of them do not work, I try to use other browsers to compile it but it also don't work

another question,

```css
<style>
 body {
 font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
 ont-size: 20px;
 }
</style>
```

It can't show the quicksand font in Firefox and Chrome, it only works in Internet Explorer 11

Comment: second question : 
ont-size: 20px; might be wrong, -- try font-size: 20px;

Comment: When I try the code above, I don't get a scroll bar...

Comment: agree with coderboy.
there is no scroll for me too.
it just open the video for me perfect as it can be.
if you had div tag, you can use overflow for it

Comment: try scroll="no" instead of scrolling="no",  working for me.
Below should also work in all browser
iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: How about reducing the height of the iframe? Does that force overflow?

Answer (score 0):

For your scrolling problem the only thing that comes to my mind is that you could have misplaced it into the wrong tag. Also maybe this helps you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

For your font question:
I don't know the font maybe you have to import it with `@font-face`, like that: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Tutorials/Typografie/Schriftformatierung#.40font-face

Also I'd like to mention that your `font-size` is missing the 'f' as you already might know from one of the comments above.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping  iframe inside a div

```
    <div style="
        height: 50vh;
        max-width: 50vw;
    ">
        
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/60ItHLz5WEA" frameborder="0" 
        style="height: 100%;width: 100%;"></iframe>
        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this feature is not supported in HTML5. But still, most of the browsers still support it.

You can use this attribute to prevent  from scrolling.

```
<iframe src="..." scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

dont use this size pixel(px)
you can use this size em or rem

font-size:2rem;

https://css-tricks.com/is-it-better-to-use-ems-rems-than-px-for-font-size/

Comment: While this is correct, it would be helpful to show the OP *Why* this is a better approach, perhaps edit your answer with references .

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/is-it-better-to-use-ems-rems-than-px-for-font-size/